# $f$ is an entire function s.t $|f(z)|=1$ $\forall z \in \Bbb R$. prove that $f$ has no zeros in $\Bbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, holomorphic-functions, analytic-functions, entire-functions

My attempt: I was trying to apply identity theorem that if the zeros of the function do have any limit point and it will be a zero function but setting $g(z)=f(z)-1$ will not help me. Can anyone help me in that!!

Comment: $f(z)$ must be of the form $f(z)=e^{iz}$ for all $z \in R$, so if it is equal to that along a line by analytic continuation it must be equal to that everywhere, and $e^{iz}$ has no zeroes other than at $-\infty$

Comment: @seth Your assumption does not seem right. For one thing, $f$ may be $e^{i z^2}$, or $e^{i g(z)}$ for any entire function $g$ that sends $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Good point, I missed that. It should be more like $f(z)=e^{iRe(g(z))}$ or something, but still it would have to be a real number and its zeroes would be in the same places I think

Comment: Perhaps Using maximum principle modulus to map upper (lower) half plane to unit disk, be helpful.

Comment: So if $I$ is the map which takes the upper half plane into a disc analytically then $f \circ I^{-1}$ takes the disc to the complex plane s.t it has modulus $1$ on the boundary of the disc. Now what?

Comment: Now the upper half plane is an open connected set if $z_0 \in Bd(D)$ so there exists a point $z \in N(z_0)$ in the interior of the disc s.t $|f \circ I^{-1}|(z)>1$ for all $z_0 \in Bd(D)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f$ is entire, so is the function $g$ defined by $g(z)=\overline{f(\overline z)}.$ The hypothesis gives $g(z)=1/f(z)$ for $z\in\mathbb R,$ which forces $g=1/f$ by the identity principle. So $f$ is invertible.